# JS + POST + FORM

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте.

Объясню на примере:
Пользователь заходит на страницу index.html с таким содержанием:

```
<form name="buy" action="script.php" method="post">
<select name="type[]" id="type" multiple>
<option value="0">Планшет</option>
<option value="1">Телевизор</option>
<option value="2">Телефон</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="OK">
</form>
```

Выбирает из выпадающего списка "Телевизор" и "Телефон" и нажимает "OK".
Страница script.php принимает данные и в случае ошибки выдаёт исходную форму обратно. JS после этого исходя из POST данных добавляет selected к полю "Телевизор" и полю "Телефон".

Как такое можно было бы реализовать (в смысле JS составляющую - т.е. интересует исключительно сохранение выбранных полей после обновления страницы)?

Наработки:

Нашел вот такой скрипт:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
/**
* Сохраняем форму. Функция принимает ссылку на форму. Форма должна иметь
* уникальный аттрибут ID.
*/
function saveFormSession(form) {
  if(!form||!form.id||!/^[^;=]+$/.test(form.id)) return;
  var data="", tok, el, safe_name;
  for(var i=0; i<form.elements.length; i++) {
    if((el=form.elements[i]).name==""||el.getAttribute("skip_form_save")!=null) continue;
    safe_name=el.name.replace(/([)\\])/g, "\\$1");
    switch(el.type) {
      case "text":
      case "textarea": tok="v("+safe_name+"):"+el.value.replace(/([|\\])/g, "\\$1")+"||"; break;
      case "radio":
      case "checkbox": tok="s("+safe_name+"):"+(el.checked? "1": "0")+"||"; break;
      case "select-one": tok="i("+safe_name+"):"+(el.selectedIndex)+"||"; break;
      default: tok="";
    }
    data+=tok;
  }
  if(data>=4000) return alert("Can't save form into cookie, to much data...");
  document.cookie="ses"+form.id+"="+escape(data);
}
/**
* Восстановить значение формы. Форма должна иметь уникальный атттрибут ID.
*/
function restoreFormSession(form) {
   if(!form||!form.id||!/^[^;=]+$/.test(form.id)) return false;
   var strt, end, data, nm, dat;
   if((strt=document.cookie.indexOf("ses"+form.id))<0) return false;
   if((end=document.cookie.indexOf(";", strt + form.id.length + 3))<0) end=document.cookie.length;
   data=unescape(document.cookie.substring(strt + form.id.length + 4, end)).split("||");
   for(var i=0; i<data.length-1; i++) {
      nm=/^[vsi]\(((?:[^)\\]|(?:\\\))|(?:\\\\))+)\)\:/.exec(data[i]);
      nm[1]=nm[1].replace(/\\([)\\])/g, "$1");
      dat=data[i].substr(nm[0].length).replace(/\\([|\\])/g, "$1");
      switch(data[i].charAt(0)) {
        case "v": form.elements[nm[1]].value=dat; break;
        case "s": form.elements[nm[1]].checked=(dat=="1"? true: false); break;
        case "i": form.elements[nm[1]].selectedIndex=dat; break;
      }
   }
}
//-->
</script>
```

Но он не работает с multiple. Как заставить его работать с multiple?

Comment: Как происходит отправка форм? Через Form Submit или через AJAX?

Comment: Отправка формы происходит через Form Submit, т.е. без использования JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если данные формы передаются через form submit с перезагрузкой страниц то заполнение формы следуе провести через php:

```
if ($error) {
    echo '
    <form name="buy" action="script.php" method="post">
        <select name="type[]" id="type" multiple>
            <option value="0"';
        if (array_search('0',$_POST['type'])) echo ' selected';
        echo '>Планшет</option>
            <option value="1"';
        if (array_search('1',$_POST['type'])) echo ' selected';
        echo '>Телевизор</option>
            <option value="2"';
        if (array_search('2',$_POST['type'])) echo ' selected';
        echo '>Телефон</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="OK">
    </form>';
}
```